# Adding SSL support to my embedded jetty server

Tags: java, web-applications, jetty, embedded-jetty

When Jetty deploys a web application, it looks for a file called `WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml` or `WEB-INF/web-jetty.xml` within the web application (or WAR) and applies the configuration found there.
This file configures an instance of org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
 ..
</Configure>
```

Now, I want to add other configurations to this embedded server, such as SSL support. This requires an instance of `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server` to be configured. I have a file `jetty-https.xml` which configures an instance of `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server`and adds the necessary configurations required.

My question is: **how do I make jetty use this `jetty-https` file.**

All my configurations are in XML based. I am running my application through jetty-runner. Version of jetty is: 9.2.**
P.S. I've already searched a lot over the internet. Just don't understand this part.

Comment: First, [Jetty 9.2 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-dev/msg02726.html), consider upgrading.  Next, you are asking about standalone Jetty when you refer to `jetty-https.xml`, but then you refer to embedded-jetty in the same question.  This is confusing, which mode do you want?

Comment: I am looking for SSL in embedded jetty.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt The question referred to as the duplicate solves it using java. I need a solution to add SSL using **XML** configurations. Is it not possible or I am not asking the right question?

Comment: Based on your response to my prior question.  XML == standalone mode, Java == embedded-jetty mode.  You said "I am looking for SSL in embedded jetty".  Hence the Java version and flag as duplicate.

Comment: There is also an additional mode you referenced in your question with `jetty-runner`, but that's just a variant of standalone (not embedded jetty).

Comment: Thanks. So, I have 2 questions. First: I am running my application through jetty-runner. Doesn't it count as embedded jetty? Second: Since I do not start my server through java code, how should I go about to add SSL with jetty-runner implementation ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172527/discussion-between-aditya-gupta-and-joakim-erdfelt).

Comment: Please ask a new, and clear, question about jetty-runner and XML use, specifically about SSL.  But know that jetty-runner is deprecated and slated for removal once Java 8 is no longer updated. (it doesn't, and cannot work with JEP 238 changes introduced Java 9, Java 10, and Java 11)

Comment: Ohk. Thankyou  !